# Magento 1 : How to disable product price update on the front-end when changing a product Qty

Tags: magento-1.9, price, addtocart, totals, qty

I want to disable the price update with qty. In default magento price calculation is "Product PriceXQty". I want to disable it and total price in the cart is product price only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

1. A coupon rule - e.g [Buy one get one free](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17465/buy-one-get-one-free)
2. Change the unit cost dynamically (cost = item price / qty) - e.g [Update price of item before adding to cart!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/update-price-of-item-before-adding-to-cart)
3. Setup tier price rule in admin
4. Create a custom discount on order totals - [Magento Add Fee or Discount to Order Totals](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/)